# Javascript: Efficiently find whether two GeoJSON features overlap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, geospatial, geojson

I need to build a JavaScript function which takes two GeoJSON features as input: Feature **A** will be a Polygon or Circle; feature **B** will be a Point, Polygon, Circle or Ellipse.

The function should return, as quickly and efficiently as possible, whether **B** "touches"  **A** in any way (whether they overlap, whether one is contained within the other, e.g.)

Extreme precision is not important (i.e. I don't care about issues arising from, say, the curvature of the Earth); I also don't need to know any details about *how* the two features touch one another, just a boolean TRUE or FALSE as to whether or not they do.

If there's a good solution that requires a module, that's perfectly fine -- the only thing that's important is that the actual function is as fast as reasonably possible. E.g. it looks like Turf can do this, but would require executing a few separate functions (intersect, contains, etc.) some of which are overly heavy.

Comment: Would https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-boolean-disjoint work?

Comment: @georg I can't really tell based on the very limited documentation for that function -- depends on how "intersection" is defined. When I get back to the office Monday I'll run some tests on it to see if it does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately there's a JavaScript port of JTS (Java Topology Suite) - library of spatial predicates and functions for processing geometry conforming to the Simple Features Specification (a standard from the Open Geospatial Consortium)

Its name is JSTS (GeoJSON support included)

https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts

- Typical examples:

Intersection of A and B

```
var intersection = a.intersection(b)
```

Difference of A and B

```
var difference = a.difference(b)
```

Union of A and B

```
var union = a.union(b)
```

Check the test suite for all the use cases including Point in Polygon tests
https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/tree/master/test

Also, visual example integrated with Openlayers (with source code):
https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/jsts.html

EDIT 1:

In case you want just one function something like this will do:

```
var intersection = (a.intersection(b) !== null) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Need to take a closer look at this -- it looks like the intersection function you mentioned will actually return the geometry of the intersection rather than a boolean true/false, which I assume must be a good deal more expensive. Will poke around and see if there's a method that does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: OK, looking a bit, I think intersectsOp (https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.index.strtree.AbstractSTRtree.IntersectsOp.html) looks like what I need. Marking this as correct, may come back with questions though! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you could find a function that returns a boolean. The better I could think of was using a Conditional (ternary) operator as in my EDIT.

Comment: Only open question is how efficient the conversion from geojson is when running at scale; will run some tests when I have a chance & note results here.